# How to insert the deleted records using trigger and procedure

Tags: oracle

I want to insert the deleted record.
scenario: When ever I receive an update on table a, I have to delete all records of tht particular technician and insert the updated records and insert the remaining deleted records of that technician in table b..

Answer (score 1):

For all the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` transactions, use `MERGE` statement.

And, to log i.e. to `INSERT` all the `DELETED` rows into another table, implement a [BEFORE DELETE trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99888). For example,

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE DELETE
   ON table_name
   [ FOR EACH ROW ]

DECLARE
   -- variable declarations

BEGIN
   -- trigger code

EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
   -- exception handling

END;
```

Add all the required logic in the trigger to insert the deleted records into another table.

And, if you have `FINE GRAINED AUDITING` enabled, then you don't have to use the trigger at all.

**Edit**  Regarding `MERGE` as I suggested above :

To `UPDATE` the destination table for records matching the source table and `DELETE` the records that doesn't match, you need `MERGE`. For example :

```
MERGE INTO destination d
  USING source s
    ON (s.col1 = d.col1)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET d.col2 = some_value
    DELETE WHERE d.col3 = some_value;
```

And, to have these `deleted` records to be `inserted` into another table, which is a `TRIGGER` action.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Don't know what's up with my keyboard and monitor display.

Comment: I don't understand why `MERGE`  should be used instead of `INSERT` , `UPDATE` and `DELETE` ?

Comment: My understanding is OP wants to `UPDATE` destination table for records matching the source table and `DELETE` the records that doesn't match. And, want these deleted records to be inserted into another table. So, the former part is `MERGE` with `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operation. The latter is a `TRIGGER` action.

Comment: Ah ok! I thought your were saying that on the _general case_. Sorry to have misunderstood you.